# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib with anything php related

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, libpng, dyld

Using any php application results in:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: image not found
[1]    4494 trace trap  php
```

Most of my php applications were installed using homebrew with the exception of composer (installed using curl)

I tried removing the the libpng and reinstalling with homebrew to no avail.

Next was to switch to latest version of libpng 1.5 as stated in the error message:

```
$ brew info libpng
libpng: stable 1.6.10 (bottled) 
http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.17 (15 files, 1.0M)
Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18 (15 files, 1.0M)
Poured from bottle
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.10 (17 files, 1.3M) *

$ brew switch libpng 1.5.18
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.17
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.10
16 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.18
```

Now the error has changed to:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Reason: image not found
[1]    6993 trace trap  phpunit
```

I'm running Mavericks (10.9.2) and PHP 5.5.1.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I suggest you run:

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
```

Until couple of minutes ago I had this problem, too. Because I have an up to date PHP version, I solved it with:

```
$ brew reinstall php55
```

Comment: Thank you, I uninstalled and re-installed homebrew completely but retrospect I think this would have been a better option.

Comment: I had the same issue with a different program (grace) and this fixed it.

Comment: Maybe helpful: It's possible ImageMagick is the culprit for this. I had a similar problem with ImageMagick obliterating /usr/local/bin/compare which I had going to diffmerge.

Comment: I didn't have to do $ brew upgrade - but $ brew update and $ brew reinstall php53 worked for me.

Comment: Warning: upgrade will update all your (outdated) formulae and might take a while!

Comment: I am downvoting because the suggestion to run `brew upgrade` is going to burn some people. Can you edit and make a note of this?

Comment: @MattMontag why is it going to burn some people?

Answer (score 43):

I followed the above (never a bad idea to keep up to date with brew anyhow) and still had the same exact issue:

```
LAPTOP:folder Username$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Then figured out a simpler way:

Search for your libpng version(s) on your box:

```
# Requires locate & updatedb for mac os x
# See Link [1] 
LAPTOP:folder Username$ locate libpng15.15.dylib
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/usr/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
```

Make a symlink:

```
LAPTOP:folder Username$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.5.14/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
```

Try again:

```
LAPTOP:folder Username$ php -v
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 16:07:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

1) [Mac OS X equivalent of locate](https://superuser.com/questions/109590/whats-the-equivalent-of-linuxs-updatedb-command-for-the-mac)

Comment: Btw, `mdfind libpng15.15.dylib` doesn't require locate hack

Comment: Thanks @JureC., I wasn't aware of mdfind. You can also use sudo find / -name libpng15 -print but the output is a tad verbose.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me, thanks :D

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Issue I had is that libpng15 is now an old version so an update would not fix.

Answer (score 20):

It's because there's no symlinks for libpng. You need to link libpng again.

```
brew unlink libpng && brew link libpng
```

And you may get some error. I fixed that error by correcting permission. Maybe it's because of uninstalled macports.

```
sudo chown -R yourid:staff /usr/local/share/man/
```

Create link again and it'll work.

Comment: On El Capitan, using homebrew-php, and this ended up being a solution for me. In addition to the above linking, I also had to run `brew link unixodbc`. But my system had ownership of that particular package.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by copying it over to the missing directory:

```
cp /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
```

brew reinstall libpng kept installing libpng16, not libpng15 so I was forced to do the above.

Comment: This will cause an additional issue when running brew doctor.     
  `Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib`

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was `libjpeg`. All I had to do was run `brew reinstall libjpeg` and everything just worked!

Comment: In my case it was `libpng`. `brew reinstall libpng` solved it

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone else runs into this problem I solved it by the following

```
brew update && brew upgrade # installs libpng 1.6
```

This caused an error with other packages requiring 1.5 which they were built with, so I linked it:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/
ln -s ../Cellar/libpng/1.5.18/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
```

Now they are both living in harmony and side by side for the different packages.  It would be better to rebuild the packages that depend on 1.5, but this works as a quick bandage fix.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has already an answer that gives a solution. But I want to give you my two cents to help people to understand the problem. Getting same issue I've created [a specific  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830183/why-phpstorm-says-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng15-15-dylib-w). I got same problem, but only with PHPStorm. And exactly when I try to run test from the editor.

[dyld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) is the dynamic linker

I sow that dyld was looking for /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib but inside my /usr/local/lib/ there was not. In that folder, I got libpng16.16.dylib.

Thanks to a comment, I undestand that my /usr/bin/php was a pointer to php 5.5.8. Instead, ... /usr/local/bin/php was 5.5.14. PHPStorm worked with /usr/bin/php that is default configuration. When I run php via console, I run /urs/local/bin/php.

So, ... If you get some dyld error, maybe you have some wrong php configuration. That's the reason because

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
$ brew reinstall php55
```

But I dont know why this do not solve the problem to me. Maybe because I have

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and none of the solutions in this thread worked for me.  As it turns out, the problem was that I had this line in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias php="/usr/local/php/bin/php"
```

And, as it turns out, `/usr/local/php` was just a symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.24/`.  So when I invoked `php -i` I was still invoking php54.  I just deleted this line from my bash profile, and then php worked.

For some reason, even though php55 was now running, the `php.ini` file from php54 was still loaded, and I received this warning every time I invoked php:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.38/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/memcached.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

To fix this, I just added the following line to my bash profile:

```
export PHPRC=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
```

And then everything worked as normal!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error that wasn't solved by `brew update && brew upgrade`. For some reason I needed to install it from scratch:

`$ brew install libpng`

Answer (score 1):

I had very hard time with this error :

> Reason: Incompatible library version: php
>   requires version 44.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides
>   version 42.0.0 Trace/BPT trap: 6

I did all the above things with brew and much more ... but it wasn't this !

Check where your library is :

> sudo find / -name libpng16.16.dylib

In my case here was the relevant result :

- /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
- /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
- /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
- /opt/X11/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

So as I'm a MAMP user it turn out that the error appeared while I was trying to update from PHP 7.1.0 to 7.1.8 ([last MAMP php available](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)) as Symfony4 require at least 7.1.3

At the end I instaled the new version of MAMP and it worked (4.1 to 4.2).
However be carreful when you're doing this, you need to backup first everything in your MAMP/htdoc folder. Also keep a backup of your custom compiled php version than can live in MAMP/bin/php. (In my case I had a special PHP version with Oracle drivers).

Also if you configured the MAMP php version to be your CLI php interpreter, you'll need to update the PATH in your .bash_profile

It should look something like this :

> export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin:$PATH

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after updating MAMP, and the custom $PATH I had set was wrong because of the new php version, so the wrong version of php was loaded first, and it was that version of php that triggered the error.

Updating the path in my .bash_profile fixed my issue.