# Enabling PNG support while installing GD.pm in Perl

Tags: perl, gd, osx-mavericks, cpan, circos

I have already installed GD.pm. I want to make sure it supports PNG.
So to check that I do this:

```
$ perl -e 'use GD; $im=GD::Image->new(); print $im->can("png") ? "yes" : "no" , "\n";'
no
```

As you see. It prints `no`.
Then I download the latest GD from CPAN with the following process:

```
> wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.53.tar.gz
> tar xvfz GD-2.53.tar.gz
> cd GD-2.44
> perl Makefile.PL 
> make
> make test
> make install
```

I expect it to contain the line like this which is a hallmark of the installed PNG support:

```
Included Features:          GD_XPM GD_JPEG GD_FONTCONFIG GD_FREETYPE
GD_PNG GD_GIF GD_GIFANIM GD_OPENPOLYGON GD_UNCLOSEDPOLY GD_ANIMGIF
GD_FTCIRCLE VERSION_33
```

But instead I got this only:

```
Included Features:          GD_GIF GD_GIFANIM GD_OPENPOLYGON
```

I wasn't successful with this command either `sudo perl Makefile.PL -options "JPEG,FT,PNG"`.
It didn't show `GD_PNG`.

What's the way to install GD.pm with PNG support?

I need it to run [circos.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/circos-data-visualization/WJ3rsfpg7vk)

**Update:**

After installing libpng and rebuilding GD

```
$ brew update && brew upgrade
$ brew install gd
$ brew install libpng
$ sudo cpan 
  cpan > force install GD
```

as adviced, I got this error:

```
$ perl -e 'use GD; $im=GD::Image->new(); print $im->can("png") ? "yes" : "no" , "\n";'
Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/GD/GD.bundle' for module GD: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/GD/GD.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
 at -e line 1.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

**Update 2:**
Finally I [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23569989/1380929) the problem by doing this:

```
$  locate libpng15.15.dylib
/anaconda/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/anaconda/pkgs/libpng-1.5.13-1/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib

$ ln -s /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib

$ perl -e 'use GD; $im=GD::Image->new(); print $im->can("png") ? "yes" : "no" , "\n";'
  yes
```

Comment: You're probably missing `libpng` / `libpng-dev`. Once those are available, you'll need to rebuild GD too.

Comment: Don't build your own. Just install the pre-built package for your platform.

Answer (score 3):

You need libraries as dependencies before making GD.pm.  In this particular case libpng is obviously missing.

Because of that dependency, I recommend that you use package managers, not CPAN, if your perl is the one that comes with your OS:

- MacPorts or homebrew for OS X
- apt-get for Debian and Ubuntu.
- yum for RHEL, Cent-OS.