# OS X Yosemite ffi-hunspell dyld lazy symbol binding failed: symbol not found

Tags: ruby, macos, ffi, osx-yosemite, dyld

Since upgrading I've been getting this error when running my tests:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN8HunspellC2EPKcS1_S1_
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN8HunspellC2EPKcS1_S1_
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

- I've tried reinstalling the gem, fresh ruby install, ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.2
- It's specific to the system hunspell version, but I can't see how to stop ffi loading that without editing the ffi-hunspell gem
- I've installed the updated xcode app and command line tools with xcode-select --install, which fixed some problems with nokogiri but not with this

I think it's an issue with Apple's hunspell 1.2 build, as [if I remove 1.2 from the ffi-hunspell gem](https://github.com/postmodern/ffi-hunspell/blob/master/lib/ffi/hunspell/hunspell.rb#L7) (with bundle open ffi-hunspell) the tests pass, assumedly loading the hunspell 1.3 I've installed with homebrew.

Is there a way to restrict where ffi looks for libraries?

Also, what's up with the system library?

Comment: Don't know if this is the issue, but have you upgraded to the latest XCode?

Comment: Yes, and done xcode-select --install again to get the command line tools / libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. optionally `brew update`
2. `brew install hunspell` to install a version 1.3
3. Point your gemfile at 
   `gem 'ffi-hunspell', github: 'postmodern/ffi-hunspell'`

It will stop loading the system library, and no more errors.

Comment: Additionally, you may have to run `brew update && brew upgrade` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22631734/308315 .. This finally got it working for me.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. The gem was updated to try to load the newer version, which updated homebrew will install, before it tries to load the older and broken system version.

Answer (score 1):

Bundling the gem from the github repo should fix this until a version newer than `0.3.0` is released to rubygems ([This commit](https://github.com/postmodern/ffi-hunspell/commit/91516637fdff9cef9bae66aefdd89e1b4a8b5831) contains a fix, but has not been released for some reason).

```
gem 'ffi-hunspell', github: 'postmodern/ffi-hunspell'
```

You should *not* need to do a wide open `brew upgrade`. Try bundling from github first.

Answer (score -1):

Often, after upgrading the OS, you'll have to rebuild your native libraries for gems. Try:

```
gem pristine --all
```

[The documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-pristine) explains it.

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, unfortunately it's not fixing the problem. It's also occurring on a fresh ruby install (rbenv).