# libpng16.16.dylib load error when executing PHP CLI with "exec" from PHP file

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, libpng

I am running PHP 5.5 on Mac OS X Yosemite.  PHP 5.5 is installed with Homebrew.

I have a .php script that has to be executed asynchronously (from CLI).  If I execute it from terminal, it works fine.  However, if I execute it within my PHP application it does not work.

Code that launches the script (run by Apache) is:

```
// 1.- Alter path so that Homebrew PHP is launched
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:" . getenv("PATH"));

// 2.- Exec PHP script in background
exec("php /path/to/my/file/script.php > /dev/null &");
```

I get the following error:

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
    /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
```

Any clues?

I already tried solution in [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib with anything php related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631026/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng16-16-dylib-with-anything-php-rel) with no luck

Comment: It's most likely a permissions error of some sort.

Comment: Which permissions are needed?  libpng16.16.dylib permissions are r--r--r--, so I can't see the difference between executing from Terminal and within PHP file (though, obviously, there must be a difference).

Comment: What are the permissions on `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: Permissions are `rwx------` (!!!) THANK YOU!  I must be blind or something, :-)  I changed `/usr/local/lib` permissions to `rwxr-xr-x` and works like a charm

Comment: By the way, if you create an answer for this, I'll be pleased to vote it up and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stat() failed with errno=13` indicates that there is a permissions error. The `.dylib` file should have read permissions, and the directories it is contained within should have the executable (`x`) bit set as well. (I think the read [`r]` bit should be set, too, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: Permissions in `/usr/local/bin` were `rwx------`.  I changed them to `rwxr-xr-x` and works like a charm.