# Error when trying to install R via Homebrew

Tags: r, macos

When I attempt to install R via Homebrew (to use for Vim-R-plugin):

```
brew install gcc
brew install r
```

Then then try to run R:

```
R
```

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/5/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.0_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
zsh: trace trap  R
```

I have searched for the error and have tried several "solutions" with little luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Potential solution from another SO question? Upgrading your homebrew build. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22631734/2456549

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Justin Licata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2456549/justin-licata) was correct.

The issue was resolved by running:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall r
```

Comment: I had to use a couple brew link --overwrite calls (as indicated by the warnings from the commands you paste), but otherwise this worked great. Thanks!