# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng.3.dylib when using php

Tags: php, homebrew, libpng

I am getting an error when running `php`:

```
$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I read this [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib with anything php related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631026/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng16-16-dylib-with-anything-php-rel) but I'm not sure if PHP was installed with brew as this command `brew reinstall php55` (or anything else like `brew reinstall php`, `brew reinstall php56`) does not work.

The next answer suggests symlinking this missing library. e.g.

```
$ locate libpng.3.dylib
/opt/X11/lib/libpng.3.dylib
/usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.dylib
$ ls -l /usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.dylib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 snowcrash  admin  18 15 Jan  2008 /usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.dylib -> libpng.3.0.0.dylib
$ ls -l /usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.0.0.dylib 
-rwxrwxrwx  1 snowcrash  admin  422632  4 May  2007 /usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.0.0.dylib
$ ln -s /usr/local/php5/lib/libpng.3.0.0.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libpng.3.dylib
$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng.3.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 20.0.0 or later, but libpng.3.dylib provides version 4.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

but it seems the version is too old so not sure what to do. I assume I need to upgrade PHP somehow or find a more up to date version of libpng.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The [workarounds for libjpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695529/65732)  applies here too.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me, was install de libjpeg:

`Get http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz, and then:
tar zxvf jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz
cd jpeg-6b
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.sub .
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.guess .
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
sudo ranlib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a`