# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib - homebrew php

Tags: php, homebrew

PHP was not working for me as I was encountering [this libpng issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702845/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng-3-dylib-when-using-php), so I reinstalled a new version with Homebrew.

However, I'm getting a similar error with `libjpeg` this time:

```
$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor` and `brew list`?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

As proposed by @jirson-tavera in the [homebrew-php repo issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4358#issuecomment-320645331), this can be fixed without overriding your brew installation:

```
wget -c http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz
tar xzf jpegsrc.v8d.tar.gz
cd jpeg-8d
./configure
make
cp ./.libs/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib
```

Comment: Besides maybe adding an odd line for clean-up, this should be the accepted answer...

Comment: Consider doing it [the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695529/65732) instead.

Comment: thanks works, I got the same issue after installed rabbitmq

Comment: I can't execute `brew switch` to downgrade the libjpeg version, it complains `switch` command not supported. So I have to choose this approach.

Answer (score 170):

Even though the solution in the accepted answer works, it's not the right way to fix the problem. It violates brew's metadata integrity.

#### Problem

The issue is that Homebrew's `jpeg` formula has been upgraded to v9 but the existing "bottled" PHP formula is still built and linked against the previous version, v8, which is no longer exists on your system.

You have a few options to fix the issue.

#### 1. Recompile `phpxx` formula from source <sup>(highly recommended)</sup>

Uninstall your php formula, and rebuild it from the source instead of using the bottled version. This way, php will use and link against the currently installed version of `jpeg`. Assuming that you're dealing with `php71`:

```
brew reinstall php71 --build-from-source
```

#### 2. Downgrade `jpeg` formula the right way <sup>(preferred over recompiling it manually)</sup>

If you haven't run `brew cleanup`, you already got the previous `jpeg` version in your brew's cellar, switch to it:

```bsh
brew switch jpeg 8d
```

If you get a *`jpeg does not have a version "8d" in the Cellar.`* error, you need to first restore it by reverting the history:

```bsh
cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core
git checkout b231469
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install jpeg
git checkout master

brew switch jpeg 8d
```

You can find out the commit hash by using `brew log jpeg` and going through the commit messages.

The downside is that there might be other formulas that require the newer version to work properly, e.g. `imagemagick`. If you face such incompatibility issues, check the first solution above.

#### 3. Downgrade `jpeg` by manually recompiling <sup>(not recommended)</sup>

Fetch the source, compile and overwrite brew's version. Refer to [Denis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45546980/65732) for details.

This is not recommended because it violates the integrity of your brew metadata. Brew thinks that it has the 8b version, however, you manually compiled 9b and overwrote the files.

#### 4. Manually symlink the old version <sup>(seriously?)</sup>

Do not [manually symlink](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4358#issuecomment-320637744) the leftover `libjpeg.8.dylib`. If the file is there, you can just `brew switch` to it as mentioned in the second solution above.

It's just the worst hack you can do here.

---

Such issues will be eventually [fixed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4358#issuecomment-320669537).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer almost positively.

Comment: First method worked for me - however, I also had to run `xcode-select --install` before I could reinstall PHP 7.1 from source.

Comment: Method 2 does not find the commit anymore, maybe because of force pushes. A workaround: instead of `git checkout b231469` I did `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/b23146936a3abb57aabb39017561e7b0c750abbf/Formula/jpeg.rb > Formula/jpeg.rb`, then instead of `git checkout master` I wrote `git checkout Formula/jpeg.rb`.

Comment: @tuomassalo Thanks for sharing your workaround. [The commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/b231469) still exists in my local clone. If it was due to a  forced push, you were not able to fetch it using `curl` either. To me, it seems like that your local clone is somehow not up to date with the remote .

Comment: @sepehr You are correct: my local copy didn't have all the history. Now that I try again, cloning the repo manually and checking out `b23...` worked fine.

Comment: if `git checkout b231469` gets error, then try this first `git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow`

Comment: It's `brew reinstall php@7.3 --build-from-source` for the PHP 7.3

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the similar problem today. The cause of the problem was a newer version of `libjpeg`. And the solution that worked was building `php` bottle from source.

Check available version of `libjpeg`:

```
$brew info libjpeg
jpeg: stable 9b (bottled)
Image manipulation library
http://www.ijg.org
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b (20 files, 724KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-08-07 at 12:06:42
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jpeg.rb
```

Install `php` from source:

```
brew install --build-from-source php56
```

---

**Update**:
If you have already installed `php` you have to uninstall it prior to building from source. It also applies to extensions.

Comment: same here just now - what exactly happened? brew updated libjpeg and its now not in the right version for php5.6?

Comment: btw. your answer outputs:
Warning: josegonzalez/php/php56 5.6.30_6 is already installed

probably should remove it first? seems scary :P

Comment: Yes, you have to uninstall `php` and the extensions. Then install `php` with `--build-from-source`.

I've looked into git history of the `libjpeg` formula and the version of `libjpeg` was update to `9b` on August 5th.

Comment: nice so this somehow broke it... well, compiling is done. it seems it works again now - thanks :)

Comment: This worked for PHP 7.1 as well, just uninstall and then run `brew install --build-from-source php71`. Issue arose for me tonight after running `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting a similar problem trying to upgrade `composer`:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
>     Reason: image not found
>   composer: PHP Phar support is required for this formula
>   Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Problem was `php` couldn't find `libjpeg` library anymore. One way to fix this is to reinstall `php` and `libjpeg`. Here's how I reinstalled them:

```bash
# find out which version of php is installed
brew list | grep php

# uninstall php
brew uninstall php70 --ignore-dependencies

# uninstall libjpeg
brew uninstall libjpeg --ignore-dependencies

# install libjpeg again
brew install libjpeg

# install php again
brew install php70
```

I was then able to upgrade everything again :)

```bash
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I solved it by downloading the libjpeg tarball manuallu from [here](http://www.ijg.org/files/) and running:

```bsh
tar zxvf jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz
cd jpeg-6b
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.sub .
cp /usr/share/libtool/config.guess .
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install

sudo ranlib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a #Optionally
```

Comment: Fixed the same problem for me, though the version compiled should be v8d now, and those libtool files don't exist on my system (still worked).

Comment: Fixed the problem for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Following command worked for me.

```
brew switch libjpeg 8d
```

Comment: This worked for me. I looked in my directory using `ls /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/` and saw two subdirectories `8d` and `9c`

Since my error was 
`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib` It made sense it was trying to load the wrong one.

Answer (score 5):

A dirty solution, that work fine for me.

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
```

Comment: There is a reason software is versioned. This will segfault your server as soon as it tries making a library call that doesn’t exist or has changed signatures.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't try Jirson's answer, but what worked for me was:

```
brew uninstall libjpeg
brew install libjpeg
```

Comment: What do you do with all the packages that are dependent upon libjpeg?

Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b
because it is required by [SNIP], which are currently installed.

Comment: @RichardAQuadling You can use the `--ignore-dependencies` option when uninstalling.

Comment: This didn't seem to resolve the issue for me. Latest jpeg version is currently jpeg-9b. libjpeg.8.dylib is still missing after following @gwg's instructions.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and the only thing that helped was to use the `--build-from-source` parameter:

```
brew install php70 --build-from-source
```

Answer (score 2):

I had also this problem. I solved it in this way:
Uninstall jpeg/8b:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libjpeg
```

Uninstall jpeg/9b:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies jpeg
```

[image: Uninstall jpeg/8b and 9b]

Re install jpeg/9b

```
brew install jpeg
```

[image: Re-install jpeg/9b]

Comment: WORKED, Yeah !!

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing this as I had the same issue when using PHP5.4. Originally, I had PHP5.6 and it was working fine. Then I downgraded to php5.4 as my app only supports PHP5.4.

Then this error came up. I noticed that I have `libjpeg.9.dylib` and PHP5.4 is looking for `libjpeg.8.dylib`.

Doing the following sorted the issue:

```
brew uninstall php54
brew install --build-from-source php54
```

Answer (score 0):

As @lifecom notes, this is fixed with homebrew's php70 update, but you might still run into the problem if `brew upgrade` is trying to update other packages before upgrading php70.

Fix this by manually updating php70 first with `brew upgrade php70` and you then should be able to run `brew upgrade` no problem (or, well, at least without *this* problem).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, especially in Catalina, the Homebrew cask for the package may exist but not be properly linked. In that case try:

```
brew link libjpeg
brew reinstall php --build-from-source
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine with `brew reinstall jpeg-xl`

Answer (score -1):

Homebrew php has been updated and no longer an issue with libjpeg