# Brew library version mismatch when running PHP

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, jpeg

After installing the php71 package with Homebrew using `brew install php71`

I get this error when I run PHP:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    55097 abort      php -v
```

Running `brew info jpeg` I get this output:

```
jpeg: stable 9b (bottled)
Image manipulation library
http://www.ijg.org
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b (20 files, 724KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-08-07 at 16:11:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jpeg.rb
```

It looks like I need to install jpeg version 8b and not 9b; how can I do this?

Comment: Please post the actual error outputs instead of images.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    55097 abort      php -v

Comment: Edit your question, don't post it in the comments :)

Comment: the error under image :)

Comment: Please run `brew reinstall php71` and try again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just faced a very similar problem.

Did this:

1. Uninstalled PHP 7.1

   ```
   brew uninstall php71
   ```
2. Installed From source:

   ```
   brew install --build-from-source php71
   ```

And now when I do php -v I get:

```
PHP 7.1.7 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2017 13:05:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Solution was found [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703296/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libjpeg-8-dylib-homebrew-php).

Edit: second command missed formula name

Answer (score -1):

All I needed to do was run this command:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

[This link](https://tecadmin.net/install-php-macos/) was helpful.