# gnuplot: dyld can't load library libjpeg

Tags: gnuplot, jpeg, dylib, libjpeg, dyld

I've installed gnuplot via Homebrew using the following command:

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt --with-x11
```

When I try running `gnuplot`, it gives me this error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgd.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    59841 abort      gnuplot
```

To load jpeg v. 9b, I ran the following:

```
brew switch jpeg 9b
```

Running `gnuplot` again produced a different error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
[1]    62256 abort      gnuplot
```

So I reinstalled gnuplot with my jpeg v.9b switched as done above:

```
brew reinstall gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt --with-x11
```

Running gnuplot produced the same error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
  Reason: image not found
[1]    70518 abort      gnuplot
```

How would I resolve this problem?

For reference, my OS is macOS 10.13.2.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar problem.I reinstalled libjpeg.
I could  solve this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45734666

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.