# R libgfortran.3.dylib not properly linked

Tags: r, gcc, homebrew

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have gcc. After installing `R` using homebrew - `brew install r` I am unable to get it working. This is the error I am getting:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6/libgfortran.3.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.3.0_1/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

When I looked into the folder I found that there is only one gcc - 5. i.e.

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc
  5
```

How can I tell R to use the above gcc rather than to look for it in 6?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631026/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng16-16-dylib-with-anything-php-rel) may be of some help.