# php dyld: Library not loaded for libldap

Tags: php, dyld

I installed ruby on my `Mac OSX High Sierra` and am running into issues now with my php installation for some reason. I'm on `php 7.1`.

Following [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1710) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631026/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng16-16-dylib-with-anything-php-rel)) Github suggestion, I tried

`brew update && brew reinstall php71`

While installing, it broke at

```
==> Pouring php@7.1-7.1.23.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.23/bin/pear config-set php_ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini system
```

With error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.23/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall php@7.1`
```

Typing in `php` into terminal throws the same error.

Other things I've tried:

- I thought perhaps it wasn't linked, so I also tried: `brew unlink libldap && brew link libldap` - but `libldap` is not supported by Homebrew
- Then [here](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql/issues/15), while unrelated to postgres, it does discuss the issue of `libldap` and says to install via `brew install openldap` (I guess `libldap` is referred to as `openldap` to Homebrew) - this installed fine but didn't resolve the issue

How can I fix this?

Comment: I shared a working solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985017/2810726](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67985017/2810726)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/32916), you need to install `openldap` and  `libiconv`.

```
brew install openldap libiconv
```

I tried it and it worked for my system.  I was originally missing the PHP `intl` extension.

Answer (score 15):

It's worked for me:

```
brew reinstall openldap
```

Answer (score 8):

Although I'm not sure why installing Ruby caused the issue, I solved the issue ultimately with:

- [According to this discussion](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql/issues/15), `libldap` is referred to as `openldap` to Homebrew. `brew install openldap` then ran `php reinstall php71`. This linked the libraries properly
- The next issue was with `libiconv`, fortunately this is easily installed with `brew install libiconv`. Rerunning `php install php71` solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

I specifically had to uninstall the offending version. You can grab this broken version from the line that looked like this:

```
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.23/bin/php
```

In OP's case, it was `php@7.1`. In my case it was `php@7.3`. After I ran the following based on my situation, everything worked

```
brew uninstall php@7.3
```

Answer (score 7):

For those who can not resolve by `brew install openldap libiconv`,
try below command:

```sh
brew reinstall openldap
brew reinstall php@7.4
brew services restart php@7.4
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have two PHP running via brew as well a XAMPP, there could be issue in environment path in .bash_profile.

```
which php
```

Try above command to see current php path. If it not accurate, set appropriate path and comment other.

```
export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
#export PATH=‚Äù/usr/local/opt/php@5.6/bin:/usr/local/opt/php@5.6/sbin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying all above solutions. Finally uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me.

```sh
brew uninstall php

brew install php
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, after running the following commands:

```
brew reinstall openldap 
brew reinstall php@7.4 
brew services restart php@7.4
```

I had to restart my computer for the error to stop and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

try to upgrade your version

```
➜  brew upgrade shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```