# PHP FastCGI build ask for local dynamic library on MacOS

Tags: php, build, fastcgi

I try to update our old FastCGI php (5.3) to a new one in php 7.3. After some effort, i can build my php 7.3 and have my php-cgi build.

But when i try to launch this 7.3 fastCGI on another computer, it gives me this error : `"dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib"`. The old php 5.3 FastCGI build don't ask me for dyld and are standalone.

How can i make my 7.3 build to be totally standalone?

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795110/php-dyld-library-not-loaded-for-libldap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php dyld: Library not loaded for libldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795110/php-dyld-library-not-loaded-for-libldap)

Comment: Thx but I want to be able to distribute my FastCGI php embedded in an application. I would not want to force my end user to have to install dynamic libraries.

Comment: My fastCGI was build on MacOS 10.15.2 Catalina