# How to solve error of Library not loaded?

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew

Facing error while upgraded homebrew

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked in Super User`

Answer (score 0):

try this command again:

```sh
brew install openldap libiconv
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to run `brew install openldap libiconv`

For compilers to find libiconv you may need to set:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib"

export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include"
```

Look out and see if openldap is already installed and run `brew upgrade openldap`

If you need to have php@7.4 first in your PATH, run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Finally run `brew services start php@7.4`