# HHVM Library Not Loaded MacOS

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I tried to install hack and hhvm to my Macbook. I followed the instructions on its official documentation. I used home brew to install hhvm. However when I try to run my first hack program I got the following error:

```
    hhvm hello.hack
dyld[56813]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/hhvm-4.149/4.149.0/bin/hhvm
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/boost/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.78.0/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libboost_fiber-mt.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort      hhvm hello.hack
```

Comment: HHVM does not support ARM64 Macs (M1+): https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/8875

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do homebrew updating libraries that hhvm depends on. I would recommend running hhvm in docker

https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/docker

php also runs into these issues
[dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib with anything php related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631026/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libpng16-16-dylib-with-anything-php-rel)

You can try some of the steps in the link above but docker is probably your best bet